# How to exclude webpack from bundling .spec.js files

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

my Package.bundle reads

```
var reqContext = require.context('./', true, /\.js$/);

reqContext.keys().map(reqContext);
```

Which basically includes all .js files.

I want the expression to exclude any ***.spec.js files . Any regexp here to exclude .spec.js files ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since `/\.js$/` allows all `.js` files (as it basically matches `.js` at the end of the string), and you need to allow all `.js` files with no `.spec` before them, you need a regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*\.spec\.js$).*\.js$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i5UG6t/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\.spec\.js$)` - the line cannot end with `.spec.js`, if it does, no match will occur
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols
- `\.js` - `.js` sequence
- `$` - end of the string.

Comment: @bernard That `/(?!\.spec\.js$)\.js$/` does not make much sense. `/(?!\.spec\.js$)\.js$/` is equal to `/\.js$/` as the lookahead result will always be true.

Answer (score 17):

Although the accepted answer is technically correct, you shouldn't need to add this regex to your webpack configuration.

This is because webpack only compiles the files that are referenced via `require` or `import` and so your `spec.js` files won't be included in the bundle as they are not imported anywhere in the actual code.

Comment: But you do `require` and `import` code from other .js files into the .spec files for testing right?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't matter. In webpack you specify the root of the app which is the first file it looks at and then it travels through all the imports made from there. It will never reach a `.spec` file since none of the application code imports from `.spec` files (only the other way around)

Comment: it does matter when spec files import source files/modules. for e.g. testing react components.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only matters if your source files import spec files which should never be the case. All test files import source files/modules, otherwise how would they test the source code? :)