# How does React Native know to ignore test files during compilation?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ts-jest, source-maps

How do I verify that *.test.ts, *.test.tsx, **mocks** folders, etc, are not being compiled into my release build React Native application?  We added a ton of tests and our build time seems to have increased.

Is there a config that explicitly points out folders and file types to ignore?

I can find a lot of article on jest with React Native, but none seemed to mention a config, so it seems like an automagical thing I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As you pointed out yourself. testfiles, are excluded by default. Metro (and I assume other bundlers as well), do this by extension (`.test.ts`/`spec.js`, etc.) as well as by folder (`__test__`/`__mock__`) so you shouldn't need to explicitly exclude them. If you deviate from the standart patterns and the tests are excluded, or if you want to exclude any other files. You can do this by:

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

This is a good question, I wasn't aware of this. But looking into it I think you should be able to exclude files in metro.config or babel.config.
I am assuming your using metro, which says the following in their docs:

```
blockList
Type: RegExp or Array<RegExp>

A regular expression (or list of regular expressions) defining which paths to exclude from Metro's file map. Files whose absolute paths match these patterns are effectively hidden from Metro and cannot be resolved or imported in the current project.
```

source:https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/

Also, you should be able to add a field `exclude` in the transformer for your babel.config. But blocklist would be my preferred option.

Comment: I've done it for my own project now. It will be reviewed tomorrow, I'll let you know if someone knows a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I found [this answer for web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57037915/7776799), and I'm assuming it works the same for React Native.  It explains that during bundling, the bundler (webpack on web) starts at the app entry file and builds a tree based on imports/requires.  This way, test files are automatically excluded since they do not export anything and therefore aren't imported in the true app's file tree.  This makes sense as to why no additional setup is necessary with jest.  Let me know if you find out anything else!

Comment: you are right, test files are excluded by default, so you shouldn't need to exclude them.